# Is there a better way to accomplish this sql query?

Tags: sql, t-sql

```
DECLARE @MinPV MONEY            -- PSV
DECLARE @MaxPV MONEY            -- PSV
DECLARE @MinGV MONEY            -- GV
DECLARE @MaxGV MONEY            -- GV
DECLARE @MinLBV MONEY           -- LBV
DECLARE @MaxLBV MONEY           -- LBV
DECLARE @MinRBV MONEY           -- RBV
DECLARE @MaxRBV MONEY           -- RBV
SET @MinPV = 5                  -- PSV
SET @MaxPV = 0                  -- PSV
SET @MinGV = NULL               -- GV
SET @MaxGV = NULL               -- GV
SET @MinLBV = NULL              -- LBV
SET @MaxLBV = NULL              -- LBV
SET @MinRBV = NULL              -- RBV
SET @MaxRBV = NULL              -- RBV

SELECT psv,* 
FROM Distributordetail
WHERE 
    (PSV BETWEEN @MinPV AND @MaxPV) OR          -- Both @MinVol and @MaxVol supplied
    (PSV > @MinPV AND @MaxPV IS NULL) OR        -- Only @MinVol supplied
    (PSV < @MaxPV AND @MinPV IS NULL) OR        -- Only @MaxVol supplied
```

The WHERE clause has 4 rows, I will need to add MANY more rows for each param that can be passed in.  Can anyone else tell me if there is a better way that this?

EDITED:

```
(PSV BETWEEN @MinPV AND @MaxPV) OR          -- Both @MinVol and @MaxVol supplied
(PSV > @MinPV AND @MaxPV IS NULL) OR        -- Only @MinVol supplied
(PSV < @MaxPV AND @MinPV IS NULL) OR        -- Only @MaxVol supplied
(@MinPV IS NULL AND @MaxPV IS NULL)         -- Neither @MinVol and @MaxVol supplied
(GSV BETWEEN @MinGV AND @MaxGV) OR          -- Both @MinVol and @MaxVol supplied
(GSV > @MinGV AND @MaxGV IS NULL) OR            -- Only @MinVol supplied
(GSV < @MaxGV AND @MinGV IS NULL) OR            -- Only @MaxVol supplied
(@MinGV IS NULL AND @MaxGV IS NULL)         -- Neither @MinVol and @MaxVol supplied
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Declare 2 additional variables to contain the [min and max values for the `MONEY` data type](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms179882.aspx), and then substitute these values for `NULL`.

EDIT: Since you want to exclude the result if both parameters are `NULL`, I would perform a conditional check before the query before changing the parameter value from `NULL` to `@MoneyMin` or `@MoneyMax`:

```
DECLARE @MoneyMin MONEY
DECLARE @MoneyMax MONEY

SET @MoneyMin = -922,337,203,685,477.5808
SET @MoneyMax = 922,337,203,685,477.5807

IF (@MinPV IS NOT NULL OR @MaxPV IS NOT NULL)
    SELECT @MinPV = ISNULL(@MinPV, @MoneyMin), @MaxPV = ISNULL(@MaxPV, @MoneyMax)

IF (@MinGV IS NOT NULL OR @MaxGV IS NOT NULL)
    SELECT @MinGV = ISNULL(@MinGV, @MoneyMin), @MaxGV = ISNULL(@MaxGV, @MoneyMax)

SELECT psv,* 
FROM Distributordetail
WHERE 
    (PSV BETWEEN @MinPV AND @MaxPV) OR
    (GSV BETWEEN @MinGV AND @MaxGV)
```

Comment: I might be able to work with this.  Gonna play around with it a bit, thank you.

Comment: I'm not sure if this will work for what I need it for, altho it is a nice way to accomplish one part of it.  There are 8 params that can be passed in, but if they don't pass in the PV params but do pass in the GV ones, I need to not show anything for the PV, and show them for the GV.  The way it is setup it will always show them the PV regardless if they pass in PV or not.

Comment: @JamesWilson Sorry, I'm confused... you say that you don't want to include PV records if nothing is passed in for PV, but in your example you have `OR (@MinPV IS NULL AND @MaxPV IS NULL)`... which is attempting to do the opposite of what you describe..

Comment: You're correct, I moved that out of my current testing area and forgot to update here.

Comment: Seems good to me, thank you for your time. :)  Saved me a whole bunch of lines of code!